# Remove one line of excel vba with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I currently am wondering if it is possible to remove a single line of vba without the error 1004 popping up. I don't want users to have to go into settings and Trust access to the vba project object model. Is this possible?
Current code (error occurs if not trust not selected):
    `ActiveWorkbook.Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule.DeleteLines 170, 1`

Comment: In order to not "Select" it, there is a code, but not so short...

Comment: see my answer and code below, I use it in some of the Auto-Tools I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want users to have to go into settings and Trust access to the vba project object model. Is this possible?

No, this is a security feature. It is impossible to programmatically toggle this security setting using VBA.

Per [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7b4fdd2e-174f-47e2-9611-9efe4f860b12) (emphasis added):

> This setting is for developers and is used to deliberately lock out
>   or allow programmatic access to the VBA object model from any
>   Automation client. In other words, it provides a security option for
>   code that is written to automate an Office program and
>   programmatically manipulate the Microsoft Visual Basic for
>   Applications (VBA) environment and object model. This is a per user
>   and per application setting, and denies access by default. This
>   security option makes it more difficult for unauthorized programs to
>   build "self-replicating" code that can harm end-user systems. **For any
>   Automation client to be able to access the VBA object model
>   programmatically, the user running the code must explicitly grant
>   access. To turn on access, select the check box.**

Comment: So there is no way to delete one line of macro without the user having to trust access?

Comment: There is no way to programmatically access the VBA Project Object Model without explicitly allowing that as an application-level setting.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the code below, see if it fits your needs:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckTrustAccess_toVBAProjModule()

'    display Windows Version installed on this PC
'    Win7.      (=6.1, 64bit)
'    Win8       (=6.2, 64bit)
'    Win8.1     (=6.3*)
'    Win10      (=10.0*)
'
'    MsgBox "Windows Version is: " & getVersion

Dim TrustAccess_VBAProjModule_Path          As String
Dim TrustAccess_VBAProjModule               As Integer

' ----- first check if "Trust Access to the VBA Project module is on ------
TrustAccess_VBAProjModule_Path = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM"

' check if Trust Access to the VBA Projct Module in the Registry is 1 or 0
TrustAccess_VBAProjModule = CInt(RegKeyRead(TrustAccess_VBAProjModule_Path))

If TrustAccess_VBAProjModule = 1 Then
    ' run your code here ...


Else '  need to auto-click the "v" by modifying the registry settings

    ' loop until Trust Access to the VBA Projct Module in the Registry is 1
    ' it might take time to modify, so use this instead of timers
    While TrustAccess_VBAProjModule = 0
        Call RegKeySave(TrustAccess_VBAProjModule_Path, "1")

        TrustAccess_VBAProjModule = CInt(RegKeyRead(TrustAccess_VBAProjModule_Path))
    Wend
    MsgBox "Initiated VBA settings, please run the Export again", vbInformation
End If

End Sub

'===========================================================

Function RegKeyRead(i_RegKey As String) As String

' reads the value for the registry key i_RegKey
' if the key cannot be found, the return value is ""
' Link : http://vba-corner.livejournal.com/3054.html

Dim myWS As Object

On Error Resume Next
'access Windows scripting
Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'read key from registry
RegKeyRead = myWS.RegRead(i_RegKey)

End Function

'===========================================================

Sub RegKeySave(i_RegKey As String, i_Value As String, Optional i_Type As String = "REG_DWORD")

' sets the registry key i_RegKey to the value i_Value with type i_Type
' if i_Type is omitted, the value will be saved as string
' if i_RegKey wasn't found, a new registry key will be created
' Link : http://vba-corner.livejournal.com/3054.html

Dim myWS As Object

'access Windows scripting
Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'write registry key
myWS.RegWrite i_RegKey, i_Value, i_Type

End Sub
```

Comment: @Noisewater  have you taken a look at my code above ? have you tried to see if it fits your need ?

Comment: I just tested this and it does work. Having the user click the add-in twice is no big deal. Thanks!

Comment: Just one problem. Although it does check and if it is not trusted, checks the box. It only works if the user opens the Trust Center/Macro Security and selects OK. This is a step in the right direction but the user still needs to give the official OK.

Comment: @Noisewater  you can use the send keys at the end of the code to do it.